# Before trigger that checks if new value is greater than value in another table

Tags: mysql

This is what I have so far:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER insert_tr BEFORE INSERT ON ordline FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF (NEW.Qty > ProdQ) THEN
    CALL ErrorMsg ('Not enough quantity to cover this order');
END IF;
END // DELIMITER ;
```

Where "ProdQ" is a column from another table, and "NEW.Qty" is the integer value being passed in.  However, I get an error saying ProdQ isn't in the table "ordline".  How can I check if the new value is greater than a value in a different table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the ProdQ is stored in another table, called Product, and both the ordline and Product tables contain a key column called ProdID, then you could do something like this:

```
if (NEW.Qty > 
   (select ProdQ from Product where Product.ProdID = NEW.ProdID limit 0,1)) THEN
```

In summary, you need to compare the NEW.Qty value against another value, not against a column.  The Product table contains potentially many rows, one for each Product, and you need to tell the trigger which of these rows it needs to take the ProdQ value from to compare against the NEW.Qty.